# Touch event in app delegate iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to achieve touch even for `UIImageView` in `appDelegate`?

Comment: What do you mean with a UIImageView in the app delegate? You should probably post some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(anyMethod)];  
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];  
[tgr release];
```

Before doing this, enable user interaction of UIimageView.

Comment: Swap and iMincy: This functionality will not work for the iOS having version below 3.2. Because in earlier versions, UITapGestureRecognizer library was not there.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful for you:

http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/